# android - StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Object?>> StreamBuilder

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm getting an error while using `Streambuilder` for my flutter application. I'm having difficulty understanding the meaning of the problem - I've tried methods that can replace different solutions, but it didn't work, it's causing problems in the compilation.

```
The following ArgumentError was thrown building StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<QuerySnapshot<Object?>, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>>#720cb):

Invalid argument(s)

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Object?>> StreamBuilder:ProfileScreen.dart:51:24
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:264:36)
#1      _ProfileScreenState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:ProfileScreen.dart:97:46)
```

My Code:

```
class ProfileScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProfileScreenState createState() => _ProfileScreenState();
}

class _ProfileScreenState extends State<ProfileScreen> {
  SharedPreferences prefs;
  AuthService _authService = AuthService();
  String mail = " ";

  get index => null;

  Future getPrefs() async {
    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      mail = prefs.getString('userMail');
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    getPrefs();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Profilin'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection('User')
                      .where('email', isEqualTo: mail)
                      .snapshots(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      List<DocumentSnapshot> items = snapshot.data.docs;
                      return Column(
                        children: [
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 20,
                          ),
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              Expanded(
                                flex: 2,
                                child: Container(
                                  width: 120,
                                  height: 120,
                                  child: Card(
                                    child: Image(
                                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                      image: NetworkImage(
                                          'https://ui-avatars.com/api/?name=${items[0].get('name')}&size=256&bold=true'),
                                      errorBuilder: (context, object, stackTrace){
                                        return Icon(Icons.person, size:75);
                                      },
                                      loadingBuilder: (context, child, loadingProgress){
                                        if(loadingProgress == null) return child;
                                        return CircularProgressIndicator();
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                width: 15,
                              ),
                              Expanded(
                                flex: 5,
                                child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    Container(
                                      width: double.infinity,
                                      child: Text(
                                        items[index].get('comment'),
                                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                      width: double.infinity,
                                      child: Text(
                                        items[index].get('email'),
                                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 20,
                          ),
                          Container(
                            width: double.infinity,
                            child: ElevatedButton(
                              child: Text('Çıkış'),
                              onPressed: () {
                                prefs.setBool('isLogged', false);
                                _authService.signOut();
                                Navigator.pushNamed(context, myRouteNames.homeRoute);
                              },
                              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 110),
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 25,),
                          ContainerWithTitle(
                            title: 'Verilerin',
                            widget: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                              child: Column(
                                children: [
                                  TargetButton(),
                                  Divider(),
                                  FavoritesButton(),
                                  Divider(),
                                  PlanButton(),
                                  Divider(),
                                  ExpensesButton()
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      );
                    } else {
                      return CircularProgressIndicator();
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests that the problem is related to accessing an index that is out of bounds in your code. Specifically, in the StreamBuilder's builder method, you are accessing an index of items without checking if it is valid. Here's the relevant part of the code:

'''

```
if (snapshot.hasData) {
  List<DocumentSnapshot> items = snapshot.data.docs;
  return Column(
    children: [
      // ...
      Text(
        items[index].get('comment'),
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
      ),
      // ...
    ],
  );
}
```

'''

In this code, index is null, so when you try to access items[index], you get the error.

To fix this, you should set index to a valid value, such as 0, before using it to access items. Here's an updated version of the code that sets index to 0:

'''

```
if (snapshot.hasData) {
  List<DocumentSnapshot> items = snapshot.data.docs;
  int index = 0; // <-- Set index to a valid value
  return Column(
    children: [
      // ...
      Text(
        items[index].get('comment'),
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
      ),
      // ...
    ],
  );
}
```

Comment: that didn't work now i have this error

`lib/Screens/ProfileScreen.dart:72:92: Error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object'.
 - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
Try correcting the operator to an existing operator, or defining a '[]' operator.